# Probability question from 2000 STEP III Exam (Question 13)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, dice

I got on the first part of the question fine but I'm really confused about the expression "**the last of the dice** to show a six does so on the $r$th roll" in the second part of the question. I interpret this line as in the following situations but none make sense.

1. If this is to ask the result of rolling the very last dice on the $r$th roll, then wouldn't it be independent from $n$ and $r$, and result simply be $p$ ?
2. If this is to ask the probability of at least one six shows up on the $r$th roll which we consider as the last roll, then wouldn't the probability simply be $1-q^n$, which is independent from $r$
3. If this is to ask the probability that result of six would never occur on the rolls after the $r$th roll, then wouldn't it simply be zero since the number of rolls would be infinity and no occurrence of a six would be impossible?

> (i) A set of $n$ dice is rolled repeatedly. For each die the probability
> of showing a six is $p$. Show that the probability that the first of
> the dice to show a six does so on the $r$th roll is $$ q^{nr}\left (
> q^{-n} - 1\right ) $$ where $q = 1 − p$. Determine, and simplify, an expression for the probability generating function for this distribution, in terms of $q$ and $n$. The first of
> the dice to show a six does so on the *R*th roll. Find the expected
> value of $R$ and show that, in the case $n = 2$, $p = 1/6$, this value is
> 36/11.
>
> (ii) Show that the probability that the last of the dice to show a
> six does so on the rth roll is $$ \left ( 1-q^{r} \right )^{n}-\left (
> 1-q^{r-1} \right )^{n}. $$ Find, for the case $n = 2$, the probability
> generating function. The last of the dice to show a six does so on the
> $S$th roll. Find the expected value of $S$ and evaluate this when $p =
> 1/6$.

Comment: The first problem is asking "Suppose you are throwing a group of (weighted) dice repeatedly.  Of course, sometimes one or more dice in the group will come up $6$ and sometimes none of them will.  What is the probability that the first time at least one member of the group show a $6$ occurs on the $r^{th}$ trial?"

Comment: I agree that the second problem is badly phrased.  I interpret it to mean:  "As you keep throwing the group of dice, keep separate track of each individual die in the group.  Eventually, of course, each of those individual dice will turn up $6$.  Consider the last of the individual dice to show a $6$ (might be more than one tied for last, of course).  What is the probability that this final die (or dice) shows a $6$ on the $r^{th}$ round?"

Comment: To illustrate:  suppose $n$ was $2$ and that you had a red die and a blue one.  On the first roll, the red one comes up $6$ and the blue one gets a $3$.  On the second roll the red one comes up $1$ and the blue one gets a $6$.  In this experiment, the final die was the blue one and it came up $6$ when $r=2$.

Comment: Hi lulu, many thanks for you comment and I did have a glimpse of the idea "keeping seperate track of dice" you mentioned, by working backwards from the expression $(1-q^r)^n-(1-q^{r-1})^n$ but didn't manage to relate this to the wording of "last". Your interpretation fully solved my doubt of going down this path. Thank you so much for enlightening.

Comment: @Black _last_ is used to tell that the last dice that shows a six for the first time shows it on the $r$th roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid none of your interpretations are correct. We have $n$ dices. Say, after the $r-1$th roll, some dice(es) have not yet shown a six even once. But, after the $r$th roll, all the dice have shown a six at least once. We can translate this into:

1. All the dice have shown a six at least once by the $r$th roll.
2. Some dice(es) show six for the first time on the $r$th roll.

Let $P(X)$ be the probability that all dice have shown at least one six by the $X$th roll. So, $P(r)$ is the probability that all the dice have shown a six by the $r$th roll. For the second condition, we need to subtract the probability that all the dice have shown a six by the $r-1$th roll(since it would imply no dice has shown a six for the first time on the $r$th roll). Thus, the required probability becomes:
$$P(r)-P(r-1)$$
It now remains to find an expression for $P(X)$. We know that $q$ is the probability that a six will not appear. So, $q^X$ is the probability that a six will not appear for $X$ rolls. The complement (at least one six will appear in $X$ rolls) is $1-q^X$. The probability is the same for all $n$ dice. Thus, the probability that at least one six will appear in $X$ rolls is$$P(X) = (1-q^X)^n$$Now finding the required probability:
$$P(r)-P(r-1)=\color{green}{(1-q^r)^n - (1-q^{r-1})^n}$$The expected value is easy from here.